# How can we reduce the size of homebrew-cask and homebrew-core folders?

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

Is there a way to reduce the size of homebrew-cask and homebrew-core folders? They are 230.7 MB and 346.5 MB respectively.

Also, `brew cleanup` does not do a whole lot, the binaries still live in the ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads folder, is this by design?

Answer (score 7):

With the [Homebrew 4.0.0 release](https://brew.sh/2023/02/16/homebrew-4.0.0/), you can save additional space:

> Unless you are developing formulae or casks, you can `brew untap homebrew/core` and `brew untap homebrew/cask` to save some space.

This freed a combined 1.1 GB for me.

Comment: `Untapping homebrew/core...
Untapped 3 commands and 6705 formulae (7,099 files, 611.5MB).
Untapping homebrew/cask...
Untapped 4264 casks (4,387 files, 302.0MB).`

Make sure you have `HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE`, `HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API` or `HOMEBREW_AUTO_UPDATE_SECS` set accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is by design.

`man brew` described this in detail:

```
cleanup [options] [formula|cask ...]
   Remove  stale lock files and outdated downloads for all formulae and casks, and remove old versions of installed formulae. If arguments are specified, only
   do this for the given formulae and casks. Removes all downloads more than 120 days old. This can be adjusted with HOMEBREW_CLEANUP_MAX_AGE_DAYS.

   --prune
          Remove all cache files older than specified days. If you want to remove everything, use --prune=all.

   -n, --dry-run
          Show what would be removed, but do not actually remove anything.

   -s     Scrub the cache, including downloads for even the latest versions. Note downloads for any installed formulae or casks will still not be deleted.  If
          you want to delete those too: rm -rf "$(brew --cache)"

   --prune-prefix
          Only prune the symlinks and directories from the prefix and remove no other files.
```

So you can run `brew cleanup -s` to delete more from the cache or `rm -rf $(brew --cache)` to delete the whole cache.

See also https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3784

> This is expected behaviour. If you want to remove everything, run the suggested rm command.

> Thanks for the answer. What's the use of keeping already installed formulae downloads files around?

> In case something goes wrong and you have to reinstall.